# Convert the path string from VSCode python into windows style

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path, copy-paste

The standard windows path string use backslash '\' to divide folders. In python, it is either converted to forward slash '/' or escaped to double backslash '\\'. Is there VSCode built-in trick or extension to covert between them? For now I have to copy it, and then paste it into a temporary new file, and then search/replace, and then copy again, which is too troublesome.
(Please note I'm asking how to do the operation with the IDE/editor, instead of how to program such conversion)

Comment: Find `copy relative path` in VSCode settings, here is [You Tube Link  Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CFfl26rMLsg&ab_channel=Code2020)

Comment: I also find this extension to convert https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YukiSadohara.easypathconverter#review-details

Comment: @Sauron thanks for the comment. well the first seems not what I'm asking. The second can only convert between back slash and forward slash, but not double backslash

Comment: To translate between Windows path strings and Python path strings, you can use the [Path Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cg-cnu.vscode-path-tools) by Sreenivas Alapati in VS Code Extension.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `os.path.normpath()`

For example:

```
import os

path = r"C:\\Users\\Administrator"
windows_path = os.path.normpath(path)

print(windows_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I'm asking the copy/paste operation with the IDE, not programming. Let me rephrase my question to make it more clear.